# Tableview Cell requires two taps to reveal the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I had a problem with table view **didSelect** method and **prepareForSegue**. I used **SWRevealController** in my app. While selecting cell it reveals the view. **Sometimes it not worked properly**. It takes two taps to reveal the view. A few months back I used old reveal view frame which contains perform block action. Its worked perfectly.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        if (i == indexPath.row)
        {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:KColorRedSelected green:KColorGreenSelected blue:KColorBlueSelected alpha:1];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:KColorRed green:KColorGreen blue:KColorBlue alpha:1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your `didSelect` code

Comment: why you used `for (int i=0; i<6; i++)`

Comment: To change the cell colours.

Comment: Do you added any gesture or Touch event methods within your class where tableview used ?

Comment: @surjeet No, I didn't used any gesture actions.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code inside of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` functions

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

   //Write code what you need 

    });
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line

`[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];`

You are calling the *delegate* method, which dequeues a reusable cell (I assume, since it's standard behavior). You do not want to dequeue a reusable cell, you want to do something with a cell that is currently displayed at `indexPath`. To do that use method from `UITableView`

`[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

The full code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // grab the selected cell and give it selected color
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:KColorRedSelected green:KColorGreenSelected blue:KColorBlueSelected alpha:1];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{
    // grab the deselected cell (if it's still visible) and give it deselected color
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:KColorRed green:KColorGreen blue:KColorBlue alpha:1];
}
```

You will also need to set appropriate color in `UITableViewDelegate` method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, since the color you once set will stay in the cell when it's reused.

Comment: I edited the answer, try now. You're overcomplicating things. All you need to do is grab one cell in `didSelect` and give it selected color, and grab one cell in `didDeselect`, and give it deselected color.

Comment: Also, in your `UITableViewDelegate` method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you will also need to check whether the cell is selected and give it appropriate color.

Comment: I am using Static Cells. In my scenario I don't need to call cellForRowAtIndexPath. Here all cells have segues also. Because of segues didDeSelelctRowAtIndexPath not calling.

Answer (score -1):

This s completely wrong method to get clicked cell

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
```

And don't use for loop as well. instead of this you should use

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to get correct cell.